# Redirecionar para página "Coming Soon" em site WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirecionamento

Estou a desenvolver um site em WordPress e não queria estar a adicionar nenhum plugin de *"coming soon"* (em breve) pois já tenho uma página para o efeito a substituir a minha homepage.

O que eu quero saber é se é possível redirecionar para essa página qualquer utilizador que entre no meu site por outro link.

Comment: Quando você diz *"qualquer utilizador que entre no meu site por outro link"*, qual seria esse *"outro link"*?

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Ricardo,

Você já tentou colocar um *.htaccess* para redirecionar?

Caso nunca tenha mexido com isso, aqui vai um link que pode te guiar: https://wpscholar.com/blog/simple-redirects-with-htaccess/

Comment: Tu também pode usar também o [wp_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) caso seja apenas um redirecionamento temporário use o status 302, mas caso seja permanente pode usar o 301.

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias formas de fazer isso no Wordpress usando PHP, como mostrado [aqui](https://gist.github.com/strangerstudios/7bbf6b2b21a9a0518a44)

```
//redirecionar nao-administradores
function pagina_em_breve()
{
    global $pagenow;

    if((!is_user_logged_in() || !current_user_can('manage_options')) && !is_page("login") && !is_page("em-breve") && $page_now != "wp-login.php")
    {
        wp_redirect(home_url("em-breve"));
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'pagina_em_breve');
```

Ou então, é possível utilizar o `.htaccess` para redirecionar todo IP diferente do seu, para a tal página:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89$ # <-- seu IP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !em-breve\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /em-breve.html [R=302,L]
```

Não se esqueça de colocar substituir por seu IP em `!^123\.45\.67\.89$`